# Azure BlobClient not writing json correctly to Storage

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a json from a API response that is stored in a var.

When I print this var I get:

```
print(json)
{"items": [{"id": "123", "name": "A"}, {"id": "456", "name": "B"}], "count": 2}
print(type(json))
<class 'dict'>
```

This var I am trying to upload as a blob to a Azure Blob Container like:

```
blob_name = 'test.json'
blob_url = f"{account_url}/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
sa_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(
    blob_url=blob_url,
    credential=sa_credential
)

blob_client.upload_blob(json)
```

Everything good, so far, a file is created in the container, however, the content of the file is:

```
items=id&items=name&items=id&items=name&count=2
```

Where I would expect it to be:

```
{"items": [{"id": "123", "name": "A"}, {"id": "456", "name": "B"}], "count": 2}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`upload_blob`* can only takes string, byte or IO object
instances as an argument. The documentation does not specify what type the *`data`* argument should be. But from the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/c8291ac6cb0dbd865da03a88dd2bcb9279e2c4a6/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py#L337) *`data`* is typed as *`Union[Iterable[AnyStr], IO[AnyStr]]`*

```
def _upload_blob_options(  # pylint:disable=too-many-statements
            self, data,    # type: Union[Iterable[AnyStr], IO[AnyStr]]
```

Where [*`AnyStr`* is a type variable defined as *`AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', str, bytes)`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr).
So one way to solve this issue is to pass the JSON string instead of the Python dictionary.

```
blob_client.upload_blob(json.dumps(json))
```